# Purple texture showing even when reimporting all the textures manually

Tags: shaders

I´ve downloaded a fbx model from CGTrader, and when I imported it to Blender, the textures where showing in a purple color, so I knew that that was happening because of Blender not knowing where the textures were.

I reimported them manually in the shader editor, and they are still in purple. Don't worry about the black textures, I've only tried it on the purple one.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the material is assigned to the vertices you want? It looks like you have indeed a third material slot for your model but assigned to nothing.

Comment: @Karl I don't think so, since if you see the material preview icon on the right tab, it still shows up in pink... So technically it looks like he's added an image texture but the texture gets deleted. But might be a bug, since he said he manually reimported the texture